# copy list of video file names to text file along with their runtime?

Tags: windows, command-line, video, batch

[How to copy a list of file names to text file?](https://superuser.com/questions/395836/copy-list-of-file-names-to-text-file)

I am linking the above page because of its relevance to my question.

Is there anything similar that can be done to output a 'plain' looking text file (or XML or CSV file) with basically the same data that the following CMD prompt produces:

```
dir > c:\list.txt
```

However, the only difference I need is the run-time of any and all video files included in the outputted file.  Can this easily be done?

Can this be done in the Python terminal or Microsoft's DOS prompt?

Comment: type a.csv <-- is that what you want?

Comment: But the "dir > c:\jjj.txt" doesn't tell me the video's length.  And this may pose another problem but my videos are of all different extentions: .mp4 .avi .mkv etc...  I do not know what kind of problems that will bring upon me...

Answer (score 2):

old answer
<s>copy /B file1+file2 file3</s>

revised answer

Use mediainfo , download it. Here is the command line version.

```
C:\>mediainfo file.wmv | find "Duration"
Duration                                 : 14mn 3s
Duration                                 : 14mn 3s
Duration                                 : 14mn 3s
```

You can also do | find "name" and get the name.

You could just grab the first line, so | head -n 1 (head requires gnuwin32),  and you could just grab the 14mn 3s

```
C:\>for /f "tokens=1-2,*" %f in ('mediainfo "a.wmv" ^| find "Duration"')
 do @echo %h
14mn 3s
14mn 3s
14mn 3s
```

You can redirect to a file.

If you put this bat file into the same directory as your videos

Here i've used the head command from gnuwin32. but if you remove | head -n 1, you'll still get the idea.

a.bat

```
for %%f in (*.*) do (
echo %%f >>y
 mediainfo %%f | find "Duration" | head -n 1 >>y
echo. >>y
)


C:\>type y
a.bat

file1.wmv
Duration                                 : 30s 0ms

file2.wmv
Duration                                 : 45s 11ms
```

Comment: you can try type,  type a.a b.b >c.c   That might work but it's possible type will change stuff so check the file size of the final file. It might work. But copy/b will definitely do it fine.  this says http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/type.mspx?mfr=true  "In general, avoid using the type command to display binary files." but it may be ok i haven't tested it enough.

Comment: I think you may be mistaken...  That made a copy of the video file.  I'm looking for the creation of a text document listing the video length or run time of said video(s) in hours or minutes...

Comment: @AdamJohnston oh I didn't understand your question, hadn't heard the expression video runtime, I see it exists, it gets 225,000 results. But video length gets 6.7 million results. i'll edit my answer