# Is there a way to take file names and insert them on separate lines of text?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, script, batch-file

I have like 500 files in folder. For example:

`1.jpg`

`2.jpg`

`3.jpg`

Is there a way to batch copy the entire file name for every file and export it into a text document separate line for each file on Windows 10?

This topic has a similar solution: [How to copy a list of file names to text file?](https://superuser.com/questions/395836/how-to-copy-a-list-of-file-names-to-text-file)

However, the formatting of the text file is not ideal:

`10/01/2012  12:14 AM       52,604 1.jpg`

Is there a way to exclude all of those additional details and only see the file name?

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using the `/b` switch:

```
dir *.jpg /b > files.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

In PowerShell, the following command will output the files as needed:

```powershell
Get-ChildItem C:\Temp | Select-Object Name | Out-File C:\Temp\Contents.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

The methods suggested by the other answers might disappoint you due to sorting

```
> dir /B
1.jpg
10.jpg
100.jpg
101.jpg
102.jpg
103.jpg
104.jpg
105.jpg
106.jpg
107.jpg
108.jpg
109.jpg
11.jpg
110.jpg
...
```

There is an alternative for cmd See [DosTips.com Sortn](http://www.dostips.com/?t=Batch.SortTextWithNumbers) which will sort on the first number independent of the count of digits.

For PowerShell there is the way to PadLeft all numbers with zeroes to a unique length with a RegularExpression.

```
(Get-ChildItem *.jpg | Sort {[Regex]::Replace($_.BaseName, '\d+',{$args[0].Value.PadLeft(10, '0') }) }).Name
```

Both solutions can be redirected into a file with a trailing `> Alljpgs.txt`